# Ethereum transaction RangeError: private key length is invalid

Tags: transactions, ethereumjs

I'm running a tutorial on how to sign an ethereum transaction programmatically, and I'm getting the following error:

```
RangeError: private key length is invalid
```

This is the code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));
var util = require('ethereumjs-util');
var tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

var privateKey = '0x...';
var publicKey = util.bufferToHex(util.privateToPublic(privateKey));
```

The error is on the last line, that attempts to get the public key from the private key.

My private key is an alphanumeric  string with a length of 64 characters. From all I can see it's the correct length.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs `util.privateToPublic()` expects a buffer. Try feeding it something more like:

`new Buffer(privateKey.substring(2,66), 'hex')`

Comment: Yes, that clears the error, thanks. `new Buffer()` btw is deprecated, so should be `Buffer.from()`.

Answer (score 3):

try to remove the 0x from the privatekey

privKey = privKey.substring(2)

I'm not sure. Different ethereum libs have different key rules.

EthersJS for example enforces 0x across the board where others might not.

Comment: Same error, after removing it.

Comment: Why would someone dislike this answer. Solved my problem and saved my day :))